# "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" how to solve this problem?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

(node:10128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.e-commerce-site.6mskt.mongodb.net
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:206:19)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10128) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

**I found this error with "node --trace-warnings ..."**

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\MyPc\Documents\Projects\E-Commerce - Project\mern-ecommerce\ecommerce-back-end\...'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: You are missing some module or path to the module is not right or the module does not exist

Comment: How to solve this problem.

Comment: you have to firstly, check the packages used are installed, then check the files that u have imported are at right path, then check if the files that u have created have module.exports in them for importing in other files

Comment: yesterday all the things worked perfectly. but today I open my backend and try to start. but I found this error. I can't understand the reason.

Comment: That happens . What is the module name that is creating the error?

Comment: Now I commented on all the other files without sever file. but still running this error. I think this error running with my mongoDB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239833/discussion-between-himanshu-singh-and-shewani).